# Elasticsearch is it possible to join folder via conditions?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have structure

```
{
  id: 1
  name: "Root folder"
  parent_id: 0,
  inherit_folder_id: null,
  inherit_permission: false,
  permissions: [some permissions]
}, {
  id: 2
  name: "Accounts"
  parent_id: 1,
  inherit_folder_id: 1,
  inherit_permission: true,
  permissions: [some permissions]
}, {
  id: 3
  name: "Finance"
  parent_id: 2,
  inherit_folder_id: 1,
  inherit_permission: true,
  permissions: [some permissions]
}
```

So, In this case I need to check if **inherit_permission = true** join by field **inherit_folder_id**. In this case for folder **Finance** I need join **Root folder** and check permissions of this folder for folder **Finance**

Comment: are this 3 document index as seperate document in Elasitcsearch or is it part of single document ?

Comment: @SagarPatel separated. If it was one it will be easy